# Table row height, text vertical center and color

Tags: tables, color, vertical-alignment

So I have the table in the following working example.

I used the solution at [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables) but still the text inside each cell is not centered vertically …

Besides, I wanted to give it a fancier look like in [Beamer table drop shadow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59646/beamer-table-drop-shadow) but I don't seem to be able to include `\rowcolors{1}{RoyalBlue!20}{RoyalBlue!5}` when working with `\multicolumn`, same for the drop shadow.

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\pbox{20cm}{Tissue-specific\\penetrance}}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\pbox{20cm}{Ubiquitous\\penetrance}}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
    \cline{2-4}
        \textbf{\pbox{20cm}{Tissue-specific\\expression}}
        & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{CLASS 1\\12 genes}}
        & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{CLASS 4\\8 genes}}
        & \textcolor{green!70!black}{20 genes}\\
    \cline{2-4}
        \textbf{\pbox{20cm}{Ubiquitous\\expression}}
        & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{CLASS 3\\32 genes}}
        & \textit{\pbox{20cm}{CLASS 2\\20 genes}}
        & \textcolor{pink}{52 genes}\\
    \cline{2-4}
    \cline{2-4}
        & \textcolor{red!70!black}{44 genes}
        & \textcolor{RoyalBlue}{28 genes}
        & \textbf{\pbox{20cm}{72 genes}}\\
    \cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A few notes beforehand: The `\bgroup`/`\egroup` is not needed as the `center` environment itself already groups its content. The use of `\small` is wrong. It is a switch so you don’t use `\small{<something>}` but (to keep it local) `{\small <something>}`. In this case, though, you could just add `\small` before `\begin{tabular}` and it makes the whole table in that size.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I have just made the changes and edited the question, but now the table looks much more condensed... how could I specify the row height so that the text remains vertically aligned? and how could I specify the color for each row (and the drop shadow)? Many thanks again!

Comment: anyone can help? I just need to specify row height... any idea???

Comment: no one?? isn't there any way to specify row height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest "cals" tables:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
}
\usepackage{cals}

\iffalse
\makeatletter
\let\olderow=\erow
\def\erow{\ht\cals@current@row=1.2cm \olderow}
\let\oldbrow=\brow
\def\browI{\oldbrow\def\cals@bgcolor{RoyalBlue!20}\let\brow=\browII}
\def\browII{\oldbrow\def\cals@bgcolor{RoyalBlue!5}\let\brow=\browI}
\let\brow=\browI
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\small
\makeatletter
\begin{calstable}


\colwidths{{27mm}{27mm}{28mm}{20mm}}
\brow
\cell{}
\cell{\bfseries Tissue-specific\\penetrance}
\cell{\bfseries Ubiquitous\\penetrance}
\cell{}
\erow
\brow
\cell{\bfseries Tissue-specific\\expression}
\cell{CLASS 1\\12 genes}
\cell{CLASS 4\\8 genes}
\cell{\textcolor{green!70!black}{20 genes}}
\erow
\brow
\cell{\bfseries Ubiquitous\\expression}
\cell{CLASS 3\\32 genes}
\cell{CLASS 2\\20 genes}
\cell{\textcolor{pink}{52 genes}}
\erow
\brow
\cell{}
\cell{\textcolor{red!70!black}{44 genes}}
\cell{\textcolor{RoyalBlue}{28 genes}}
\cell{\bfseries 72 genes}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The table looks good even without tuning:

[image: Slide with a table]

If you want to experiment with row colors and height, change "iffalse" to "iftrue". I have no experience with drop shadows, therefore can't recommend anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of in between the no-space in cells of your question and the space found in olpa's answer.

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[oldsyntax]{stackengine}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
{\small
\Sstackgap=2pt%
\def\stackalignment{l}%
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{}
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\stackanchor[1pt]{Tissue-specific}{penetrance}}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\stackanchor[1pt]{Ubiquitous}{penetrance}}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
    \cline{2-4}
        \textbf{\stackanchor[1pt]{Tissue-specific}{expression}}
        & \textit{\stackanchor{CLASS 1}{12 genes}}
        & \textit{\stackanchor{CLASS 4}{8 genes}}
        & \textcolor{green!70!black}{20 genes}\\
    \cline{2-4}
        \textbf{\stackanchor[1pt]{Ubiquitous}{expression}}
        & \textit{\stackanchor{CLASS 3}{32 genes}}
        & \textit{\stackanchor{CLASS 2}{20 genes}}
        & \textcolor{pink}{52 genes}\\
    \cline{2-4}
    \cline{2-4}
        & \textcolor{red!70!black}{44 genes}
        & \textcolor{RoyalBlue}{28 genes}
        & \textbf{72 genes}\\
    \cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[EDIT: This MWE uses obsolete stackengine syntax for setting stackgap lengths (e.g., \Sstackgap=1ex), which prevented scalable lengths from scaling under a fontsize change. Version 2 of the package (submitted 7/11/13) remedies the problem with a small syntax change.]