# Adding a shadow to a longtable?

Tags: longtable, shadows

I've already found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59649/21841) on how to add a shadowbox around a normal tabular environment. I'd like to add a shadowbox to a `longtable` environment. Is this possible at all?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Ze} & \textbf{Header} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \endfoot
    Lorem & ipsum \\
    dolor & sit \\
    amet & consectetur \\
    adipiscing & elit \\
    Nunc & nec \\
    sem & eu \\
    dolor & ultrices \\
    suscipit & Donec \\
    eleifend & leo \\
    a & urna \\
    vulputate & suscipit \\
    Praesent & in \\
    nunc & purus \\
    Quisque & ut \\
    nulla & varius \\
    aliquam & risus \\
    consectetur & dictum \\
    nulla & Nullam \\
    at & aliquet \\
    nisi & Suspendisse \\
    quis & mattis \\
    leo & Curabitur \\
    non & neque \\
    mollis & porta \\
    quam & feugiat \\
    molestie & mi \\
    Curabitur & ornare \\
    nibh & nec \\
    orci & euismod \\
    auctor & Nulla \\
    sagittis & nunc \\
    non & euismod \\
    porta & Morbi \\
    molestie & dictum \\
    purus & a \\
    pharetra & magna \\
    dictum & vitae \\
    Aliquam & bibendum \\
    dui & quam \\
    vitae & euismod \\
    lorem & tristique \\
    nec & Morbi \\
    lacinia & tellus \\
    et & hendrerit \\
    mollis & Cras \\
    et & sem \\
    in & sapien \\
    mattis & hendrerit \\
    ac & vitae \\
    velit & Maecenas \\
    interdum & gravida \\
    dui & fringilla \\
    vehicula & mauris \\
    adipiscing & ac \\
    Ut & dignissim \\
    sapien & dignissim \\
    semper & fermentum \\
    diam & purus \\
    mattis & dui \\
    ut & consectetur \\
    ligula & nibh \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

([credit](http://desertsandbeyond.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/long-table-and-chairsshadow-shot.html))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color,array}
\def\lsdw{\smash{\lower5pt\rlap{\textcolor[gray]{.9}{\vrule width 5pt height\ht\strutbox depth \dp\strutbox}}}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{|l|l!{\vline\lsdw}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Ze} & \textbf{Header} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \multispan{2}%
    \kern5pt\textcolor[gray]{.9}{\leaders \vrule height 5pt\hfill}\mbox{}\kern-5pt
    \endfoot
    Lorem & ipsum \\
    dolor & sit \\
    amet & consectetur \\
    adipiscing & elit \\
    Nunc & nec \\
    sem & eu \\
    dolor & ultrices \\
    suscipit & Donec \\
    eleifend & leo \\
    a & urna \\
    vulputate & suscipit \\
    Praesent & in \\
    nunc & purus \\
    Quisque & ut \\
    nulla & varius \\
    aliquam & risus \\
    consectetur & dictum \\
    nulla & Nullam \\
    at & aliquet \\
    nisi & Suspendisse \\
    quis & mattis \\
    leo & Curabitur \\
    non & neque \\
    mollis & porta \\
    quam & feugiat \\
    molestie & mi \\
    Curabitur & ornare \\
    nibh & nec \\
    orci & euismod \\
    auctor & Nulla \\
    sagittis & nunc \\
    non & euismod \\
    porta & Morbi \\
    molestie & dictum \\
    purus & a \\
    pharetra & magna \\
    dictum & vitae \\
    Aliquam & bibendum \\
    dui & quam \\
    vitae & euismod \\
    lorem & tristique \\
    nec & Morbi \\
    lacinia & tellus \\
    et & hendrerit \\
    mollis & Cras \\
    et & sem \\
    in & sapien \\
    mattis & hendrerit \\
    ac & vitae \\
    velit & Maecenas \\
    interdum & gravida \\
    dui & fringilla \\
    vehicula & mauris \\
    adipiscing & ac \\
    Ut & dignissim \\
    sapien & dignissim \\
    semper & fermentum \\
    diam & purus \\
    mattis & dui \\
    ut & consectetur \\
    ligula & nibh \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool solution, but it has a slight problem: there are white horizontal lines in the right-hand shadow - barely visible lines between all table lines and wider lines wherever a `\hline` was added to the table. Is there anything I could do about these?

Comment: @vwegert put a bit of an overlap, change  `\ht\strutbox` to `\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+2pt\relax `

Comment: There's another issue: The changes to the footer creates a weird side effect with the left-hand border line - see http://imagebin.org/275667. I haven't been able to find out what exactly causes this issue - I haven't even been able to reproduce it with the MWE above. After about an hour tweaking the table, I'll take a break and try again tomorrow. I'd be glad for any suggestion, though…

Comment: @vwegert I don't see that, see image I added to answer. You may need to post code that generates the problem (perhaps as new question)

Comment: I've narrowed the issue down to the `arydshln` package, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142275/combine-arydshln-and-longtable-with-fake-shadowbox