# Combine arydshln and longtable-with-fake-shadowbox?

Tags: longtable, arydshln

I have tried to use [the solution provided by David Carlisle to add a `\shadowbox`-like shadow to a `long table`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142102/21841) in my document and ran in to a strange issue:

[image: table border line gone AWOL]

After some poking around, I've narrowed the issue down to the `arydshln` package. I don't even have to use that package in the table in question -- as soon as I load it, the table gets distorted. From the package documentation I get the impression that there's quite a history of incompatibilities between `arydshln` and `longtable` - have I just found the next one? Is there a workaround -- or an alternative to `arydshln`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow,array}
% \usepackage{arydshln} Enabling this line breaks the table, although the package is not used at all...

\def\lsdw{\smash{\lower5pt\rlap{{\vrule width 4pt height\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+2pt\relax depth \dp\strutbox}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l!{\vline\lsdw}}
\hline 
X \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multispan{1}\kern4pt{\leaders \vrule height 4pt\hfill}\mbox{}\kern-4pt
\endfoot    
Y \\\pagebreak
\hline
Z \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

The package redefines `|` but `!{\vline}` is equivalent to the original definition and still works. Also you have a notch in your shadow as you used 4pt in most places but 5pt in one:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow,array}


 \usepackage{arydshln}% Enabling this line breaks the table, although the package is not used at all...




\def\lsdw{\smash{\lower4pt\rlap{{\vrule width 4pt height\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+2pt\relax depth \dp\strutbox}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{!{\vline}l!{\vline\lsdw}}
\hline 
X \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multispan{1}\kern4pt{\leaders \vrule height 4pt\hfill}\mbox{}\kern-4pt
\endfoot    
Y \\\pagebreak
\hline
Z \\
\hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```